# To catch a thief: intentionally leaving something of value out to entice a thief to steal

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

One trick to catch a thief is to intentionally leave something of value out in an effort to entice a thief to steal. For example, you might leave a sparkly set of cuff links out on your desk at work to see if anyone has stick fingers.

Two-part question:

1. Is there a word which identifies the item left out to entice the thief? "Bait" comes to mind, but I hope for a word more specific to this situation.
2. Is there a word/phrase/idiom which identifies this technique? The action of leaving something out to entice a thief to steal.

Comment: None of the synonyms for [baited trap work?](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/baited%20trap)

Comment: "Honey pot" is a term used in computerdom, for a trap set to catch a hacker.

Comment: I was going to say *honey pot* too. Also *sting*. I'm not sure how *bait* is too broad a word. Another possible word is *decoy*, but it's not clear if that's more or less broad—it would depend on how it's viewed.

Comment: There is also [**entrapment**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/entrapment): The action of tricking someone into committing a crime in order to secure their prosecution.